# Removing Anti aliasing effect from images

Tags: image, image-processing, antialiasing, edge-detection

How do we detect the smooth edges due to anti aliasing property of an image.
I am having n number of PNG images with smooth edges, I want to remove and replace it with background.
I am trying to remove them with some script.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the image and maybe the image how you want it to turn out? Furthermore, do you want this done in code (e.g. php or c#) or just once (e.g. in photoshop or gimp)?

Comment: Can you explain a bit better?

Comment: @realbart:   i want to solve this with c#. and i need some algorithm which will detect the smoothe edges of image and replace them with background.

Comment: Kindly show us an image example so we don't waste our time guessing or proposing horrendously complicated solutions for what may be a trivial problem.

Comment: [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=anti+aliased+image&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&imgil=8OPcX8UcqMBAYM%253A%253BiulYiX6xYkDPkM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.smashingmagazine.com%25252F2009%25252F11%25252Fthe-ails-of-typographic-anti-aliasing%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=8OPcX8UcqMBAYM%253A%252CiulYiX6xYkDPkM%252C_&biw=1366&bih=657&usg=__3xvOFF4Yw4vqgxpE-5VdLdoc3OY%3D&ved=0CDUQyjdqFQoTCOuXotmd3ccCFQbsFAodNhQCZw&ei=nHrpVevZJobYU7aoiLgG#imgrc=8OPcX8UcqMBAYM%3A&usg=__3xvOFF4Yw4vqgxpE-5VdLdoc3OY%3D)                              This is one example where i want to detect border of character "A"

Answer (score 1):

This is a non trivial problem. It is closely related to matting.
Basically, for each antialiased boundary pixel, you need to solve the [matting equation](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs129/results/final/valayshah/): 
*I=a*F+(1-a)*B* where the pixel value I is a convex combination (*a* and *(1-a)*) of the foreground color *F* and the background color *B*. 
From the image you only know *I* and you need to calculate *a*.

Look into the matting algorithms.
There are hundreds of papers on the subject. Here's but a small sample from first search results:

- [A Global Sampling Method for Alpha Matting](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kahe/publications/cvpr11matting.pdf)
- [A Closed Form Solution to Natural Image Matting](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs129/results/final/valayshah/Matting-Levin-Lischinski-Weiss-CVPR06.pdf)
- [Poisson Matting](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2006/DataDriven/bib/matting/sun04.pdf)

Comment: can you provide me some relevant link for matting algorithm

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But i have a single background and it is easy for me to detect foreground pixels but i need only those foreground pixels due to anti aliasing

Comment: If you only have 2 colors for FG and BG, then you know *I*, *F* and *B* and can easily solve for alpha (`alpha=(I−B)/(F−B)`).

Comment: but foreground can have one or more color but any way your help solved my problem thank you :)